# Не работает удаление предметов из инвентаря

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Пробовал сделать инвентарь по данному видео 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-OpWcRhgJ0
Практически все работает кроме удаления предметов из инвентаря.
Когда дописал весь код попробовал запустить все заработало, единственное я не правильно указал путь к префабу сферы, после исправления вещи перестали выбрасываться, уже несколько раз перепроверял код, перезаписывал все заново - но проблема не исчезает.
Мой код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

List<Item> list;
public GameObject inventory;
public GameObject container;

// Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        list = new List<Item>();
    }

// Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1))
        {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5.0F))
            {                
            Item item = hit.collider.GetComponent<Item>();
                if (item != null)
                {
                list.Add(item);
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.I))
        {
            if (inventory.activeSelf)
            {
            inventory.SetActive(false);
            for (int i = 0; i < inventory.transform.childCount; i++) {
                    if (inventory.transform.GetChild(i).transform.childCount > 0)
                    {
                    Destroy(inventory.transform.GetChild(i).transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            inventory.SetActive(true);
            int count = list.Count;
            for(int i =0; i<count; i++){
                Item it= list[i];
                if (inventory.transform.childCount >= i)
                    {
                    GameObject img = Instantiate(container);
                    img.transform.SetParent(inventory.transform.GetChild(i).transform);
                    img.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(it.sprite);
                    img.AddComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => remove(it, img));
                    }
                else break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void remove(Item it, GameObject obj)
    {
    GameObject newo = Instantiate<GameObject>(Resources.Load<GameObject>(it.prefab));
    newo.transform.position = transform.position + transform.forward + transform.up;
    Destroy(obj);
    list.Remove(it);
    }
}
}
```

[Параметры основного скрипта](http://joxi.ru/vAWDpgYHlqOOrW)
[Параметры скрипта который на кубе](http://joxi.ru/l2ZvQ0VtLE7k2J)
[Параметры скрипта который на сфере](http://joxi.ru/brRDp78H6YO621)

Comment: не силен в юнити, но если верить автору видео и самому видео, то код у вас идентичен тому что на видео. Подозреваю что вы что-то напутали или не доделали в тех местах, где надо делать настройки в интерфейсе среды, на видео их плохо видно, проверяйте.

Comment: Перепроверьте по видео инструкции, которой пользовались. Код совпадает до буквы, значит что-то другое проглядели. Автор очень непоследовательно вносил изменения в некоторых местах.

Comment: И я о том же, как писал выше - проблема началась именно после исправление ошибки у сферы, пока не исправил куб отлично выбрасывался и подбирался.

Comment: @edvardpotter, предмет только не выбрасывается? Или еще не поднимается?

Comment: @nust199, https://pp.vk.me/c633728/v633728859/128fa/iFr0R0Mlh0c.jpg  https://pp.vk.me/c633728/v633728859/12922/Z5Kq2PXnkPQ.jpg https://vk.com/photo165443859_399194848  - Как видите, все отлично подбирается, не реагирует на клик по картинке. Возможно в дебаге как-то проверить был ли клик?

Comment: В первую очередь, нужно проверить, вызывается ли вообще метод remove(), можно дебагом, можно просто воткнуть в него вызов Debug.Log().

Comment: Пробовал так: `img.AddComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => { Debug.Log(); remove(it, img); });`, Сообщение не выводится, ощущение что на элементе вообще не работает клик.

Comment: Раз не выводится, то это уже не ощущание, а правда не работает. Следующая мысль — выполняется ли вообще этот кусок кода, который с подпиской, но раз картинка назначается, то работает. Дальше тогда стоит изучить в редакторе запущенную игру, а именно кнопки эти, они наверное съехали или ужались до одного пикселя, вот и не нажимаются.

Comment: @MaximKamalov, `img.AddComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => remove(it, img));`- я не задаю размер кнопки, кнопка по сути это и есть картинка, если бы они ужались или съехали то тогда и картинка бы ужалась

Comment: @edvardpotter Все равно, стоит посмотреть, если не размер или положение, то показывается ли там в инспекторе событие. Если нет, добавьте его вручную и попробуйте снова удалить предмет из инвентаря.

Comment: @MaximKamalov, http://joxi.ru/8AnX9Z0TWozWmO

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35234/discussion-between-maxim-kamalov-and-edvardpotter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую описать решение так, чтобы оно, быть может, помогло тому, кто на этот вопрос наткнется в будущем.

Итак, если все работает, кроме того, что что-то должно произойти по клику на кнопке, но не происходит, присмотритесь, регистрируется ли вообще клик как таковой. Если кнопка не слишком сильно кастомизировалась, то должны быть неяркие анимации на наведении и клике.

Если после проверки оказалось, что кнопка/интерфейс совсем никак не реагируют на мышь, перепроверьте, все ли составляющие на месте:

- Canvas, Canvas Scaler, Graphics Raycaster в объекте Canvas
- Объект **EventSystem** в корне сцены с Event System и Standalone Input Module (если версия Unity старая, вместе последнего могут быть несколько модулей).